# Estimating focal length using light

Tags: optics, visible-light, vision

I am considering how to estimate the focal length of a dynamic lens (such as biological lenses) non-invasionally, i.e., without harming the animal. The mammal lens changes its shape depending on neuronal signalling to a tensor muscle (the ciliary body). These shape shifts alter the focal properties of the lens itself.

Is there any obvious way to do this in optics that I have overlooked? e.g., with specialised instruments. Data acquisition should be continuous with >10 updates per second.

My own thoughts involve detecting light reflection from the lens and using this as a proxy for lens properties.

Comment: This is a well-considered problem in bio-optics, particularly as regards the human eye (where it is obviously an important medical task). Have you looked at the human ophthalmology literature?

Comment: Thank you for responding, Emilio. I did look at the literature. Two key methods are used for objective measurements of focal properties in human patients: autorefraction and retinoscopy. I am looking closer at autorefraction as a possible high speed solution.

Comment: Emilio Pisanty is correct - modern opthalmology instrumentation performs auto measurement on functioning eyeballs very quickly (I know from personal experience).  Talk to your local eye doctor and do a Google search for more details.